# log4net colored console is not working

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm using log4net for two different log files and for colored console, the files works fine but the console is always empty.

in the app.config I have

```
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <priority value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleOutAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="PortalLoggerAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ApplicationLoggerAppender" />
    </root>

    <appender name="ConsoleOutAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
 <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
        <loggerToMatch value="ApplicationLogger" />
      </filter>
      <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <foreColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <foreColor value="Yellow, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <foreColor value="Cyan" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <foreColor value="Green" />
      </mapping>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{dd/MM HH:mm:ss} [%level] %newline%message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="PortalLoggerAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Results/PortalLog_%property{DateTime}_app.log" />
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
        <loggerToMatch value="PortalLogger" />
      </filter>
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
      <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
      <countDirection value="1" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{dd/MM HH:mm:ss} [%level] %newline%message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ApplicationLoggerAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Results/ApplicationLog_%property{DateTime}_app.log" />
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
        <loggerToMatch value="ApplicationLogger" />
      </filter>
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
      <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
      <countDirection value="1" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{dd/MM HH:mm:ss} [%level] %newline%message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="PortalLogger" additivity="false">
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="PortalLoggerAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="ApplicationLogger" additivity="false">
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ApplicationLoggerAppender"/>
    </logger>


    </log4net>
```

Any idea why log4net is not printing to the console?
I want that the application logger will be written also in the console.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you show how the logger is initialized in the code?

Answer (score 2):

You've specifically set `additivity` to `false`, which [as per the docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Additivity.html) means that:

> the appenders found in the ancestors of this logger are not used

meaning that those configured in your `root` at the top are being ignored.  Either remove `additivity` or set it to `true` (its default), or add your console appender explicitly to this logger too.

Answer (score 2):

To use log4net colored console use the below steps:

1. Install the below nuget:

Install-Package Log4Net_Logging -Version 1.1.0

2. Use the below log4net.config

```
      <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ManagedColoredConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level: %message%newline" />
        </layout>
        <mapping>
          <level value="FATAL" />
          <foreColor value="White" />
          <backColor value="Red" />
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
          <level value="ERROR" />
          <foreColor value="Red" />
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
          <level value="WARN" />
          <foreColor value="Yellow" />
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
          <level value="INFO" />
          <foreColor value="Gray" />
          <backColor value="Black" />
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
          <level value="DEBUG" />
          <foreColor value="DarkBlue" />
          <backColor value="Gray" />
        </mapping>
      </appender>

      <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="Log.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="false" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level[%logger]: %message%newline" />
        </layout>
      </appender>

      <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      </root>
    </log4net>
```

3. Setup in controller

```
        {
            Log.SetUp(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), "log4net.config");
        }
```

4. Start logging:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {


            Log.Info(this, "This is Info logging");
            Log.Debug(this, "This is Debug logging");
            Log.Error(this, "This is Error logging");
            Log.War(this, "This is warning");


            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it I just added the console appender to the application logger  :)

```
 <logger name="ApplicationLogger" additivity="false">
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ApplicationLoggerAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleOutAppender"/>
    </logger>
```